# Base Adapter is not working

Tags: android, baseadapter

Hi I am working on BaseAdapter  , but always my last item is showing .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    SearchViewHolder orderViewHolder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        orderViewHolder = new SearchViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list_row, null);
        orderViewHolder.setproductname((TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.orderTitle));        
        }
        convertView.setTag(orderViewHolder);
    } else {
        orderViewHolder = (SearchViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i<msearchproductname.size();i++) {
        System.out.println("@@ value of productname !!!!:"+msearchproductname.get(i));
        orderViewHolder.getproductname().setText(""+msearchproductname.get(i));  
    }

    return convertView;}
```

Even output of

```
System.out.println("@@ value of productname !!!!:"+msearchproductname.get(i));
```

is same as we want.

What is happening wrong here. In textView it is showing always last item . Please help me.Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: what does this line print Log.i("debug", msearchproductname.size); ?

Comment: msearchproductname.size is list which value is 5

Comment: You need to clean up your pasted code.  Looks like there's an extra } in there.  It's also hard to read when things are tabbed randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you need to remove the loop and do it this way

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    SearchViewHolder orderViewHolder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        orderViewHolder = new SearchViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list_row, null);
        orderViewHolder.setproductname((TextView)convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.orderTitle));
        convertView.setTag(orderViewHolder);
    } else {
        orderViewHolder = (SearchViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    } 

    orderViewHolder.getproductname().setText(""+msearchproductname.get(position));  
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response orderViewHolder.getproductname().setText(""+msearchproductname.get(i));  
this better or orderViewHolder.getproductname().setText(""+msearchproductname.get(position));

Comment: this one orderViewHolder.getproductname().setText(""+msearchproductname.get(position));

Comment: I am checking it...Let you kknow

Comment: I want to show header in first row of listview. How can i achieve it?

Comment: @BlueGreen ask a new question about it

Comment: I am blocked not able to ask new question..May you please edit your answer. It will be really helpful  for me

Comment: what does your Header contain ? a text ?

Comment: check this link http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html

Comment: means that i need to use as else {  v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61257/discussion-between-blue-green-and-nadir-b).